# html/css, make a button look like a div

Tags: html, css

HTML Buttons allows you to hit both enter or space to hit the button. However, using a button also comes with a bunch of CSS that ruins how we want our button to look.

Is there a relatively futureproof, simple way to fix this using CSS? Just looking at the computed CSS from chrome, the button adds a whooole lot of CSS attributes.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/ ... you are able to see the CSS added, then simply change them

Comment: Why would you want your button to look like a div? If you want a div to be clickable that can be done through JavaScript no need for a button.

Comment: @Curious13 This is worse from an accessibility perspective.

Comment: What does a div "look like"?  It's just a generic container, it can look like almost anything.

Comment: @Jeremy regarding the accessibility part, you can use the `role="button"`attribute. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CSS styles you should always be able to apply to HTML buttons:

1. background-color -> change the background colour of a button.
2. font-size -> change the font size of a button label.
3. padding -> change the padding of a button.
4. border-radius -> add rounded corners to a button.
5. border property -> add a coloured border to a button.
6. box-shadow property -> add shadows to a button.

Here's a coloured border button example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: white; /* button background */
    color: black; /* label colour */
    border: 2px solid #0040ff; /* 2px blue line border */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* rounded corner style */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>A styled button.</h2>

<button class="button">Button label</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it with just:

```
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Here's button heaven for you. Still one of the best https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp